# Select keep value when ngOptions array change, and select new value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, so, here's an example:

https://jsbin.com/sezojuriyu/edit?html,output

What I'm trying to do is:

1. User selects a value in the drop down.
2. The data behind the drop down changes (click the 'change array' button)
3. Since the currently selected value isn't in the new data set, have the value set to the first value in the new data set.

Ideally, it'd be great that when this happens, the `ng-model` never sets a blank/null value to the model.

It seems like there's something simple I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: you want to set the first value to array as selected ?

Comment: while your question makes sense, what you are trying to accomplish and why you are doing it this way do not.  since `ng-model` creates a two way binding between the `<select>` box and the JavaScript model, replacing the select list with some other list will break the binding.  The JavaScript variable is still set to the same value, even though that value doesn't exist in the list anymore.  If you *really* need to dynamically replace the list, you'll also have to dynamically change the model variable, but why you would do this at all isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, but you could make it a part of your changeIndex function. Just add the line:

```
$scope.selectedValue = $scope.data[$scope.arrayIndex][0];
```